# finding the minimum window substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, substring

the problem says to create a string, take 3 non-consecutive characters from the string and put it into a sub-string and print the which character the first one is and which character the last one is.

```
str="subliminal"
sub="bmn"

n = len(str)-3

for i in range(0, n):
    print(str1[i:i+4])
    if sub1 in str1:
        print(sub1[i])
```

this should print 3 to 8 because b is the third letter and n is the 8th letter.

i also don't know how to make the code work for substrings that aren't 3 characters long without changing the code in total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant. I assume that the substring is already valid, which means that it contains non consecutive letters. Then I get the first and last letter of the substring and create a list of all the letters in the string using a list comprehension. Then i just loop through the letters and save where the first and last letter occur. If anything is missing, hmu.

```
sub = "bmn"
str = "subliminal"

first_letter = sub[0]
last_letter = sub[-1]

start = None
end = None

letters = [let for let in str]

for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    if letter == first_letter:
        start = i
    if letter == last_letter:
        end = i

if start and end:
    print(f"From %s to %s." % (start + 1, end + 1)) # Output: From 3 to 8.
```

Answer (score 1):

Some recursion for good health:

```
def minimum_window_substring(strn, sub, beg=0, fin=0, firstFound=False):

    if len(sub) == 0 or len(strn) == 0:
        return f'From {beg + 1} to {fin}'
    elif strn[0] == sub[0]:

        return minimum_window_substring(strn[1:], sub[1:], beg, fin + 1, True)

    if not firstFound:
        beg += 1
    return minimum_window_substring(strn[1:], sub, beg, fin + 1, firstFound)
```

---

### Explanation:

The base case is if we get our original string or our sub-string to be length 0, we then stop and print the beginning and the end of the substring in the original string.

If the first letter of the current string is equal then we start the counter (we fix the beginning "beg" with the flag "firstFound") Then increment until we finish (sub is an empty string / original string is empty)

### Something to think about / More explanation:

If for example, you ask for the *first* occurrence of the substring, for example if the original string would be "**s**ububu**s**ubulum" and the sub would equal to "sbl" then when we hit our first "s" - it means it would 100% start from there, because if another "sbl" is inside the original string - then it must contain the remaining letters, and so we would say they belong to the first **s**. (A horrible explanation, I am sorry) what I am trying to say is that if we have 2 occurrences of the substring - then we would pick the first one, no matter what.

**Note:** This function does not really care if the `sub`-string contains consecutive letters, also, it does not check whether the characters are in the string itself, because you said that we must be given characters from the original string. The positive thing about it, is that the function can be given more than (or less than) 3 characters long substring

When I say "original string" I mean `subliminal` (or other inputs)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it works :)
can i ask what the "firstFound" flag is for?

Comment: @ohmygod The flag is to stop incrementing the beginning, if we find the beginning- we set it to True meaning that we found it and started counting.

Because I cannot comment on other's answers I will say it here, that Honn's answer is not complete, as it cannot recognize between duplicates, try for example `sub = "lma"` or `lml` on the string `subliminal`, and of-course, you can only use it for 3+ letters only, and not 2 for example. Actually, it does not work either for regular inputs such as `sia`..

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways you could do it,

here is a soultion,

```
import re 
def Func(String, SubString):
    patt = "".join([char + "[A-Za-z]" + "+" for char in sub[:-1]] + [sub[-1]])
    MatchedString = re.findall(patt, String)[0]
    FirstIndex = String.find(MatchedString) + 1
    LastIndex = FirstIndex + len(MatchedString) -1 
    return FirstIndex, LastIndex
string="subliminal"
sub="bmn"
FirstIndex, LastIndex = Func(string, sub)
```

This will return 3, 8 and you could change the length of the substring, and assuming you want just the first match only